# 3D topographic progress compensation by the least squares method.

Tags: 3d, least-squares

I'm looking for an explanation of the least squares method used in the case of a correction of 3D point network. We have reference points with known coordinates XYZ, we calculate intermediate points based on chaining from the starting point (reference point), as we reach the end point (other reference point), then we calculate the difference between the measured coordinates of the end point and known coordinates of the end point, so the difference is the cumulative error, so we have to split the cumulative error between all measured points by the least square methods. So please if someone have a document explaining the mathematical formulas, what to do, and sample application of this method?

thank you very much.